# Typeorm + Firebase functions: "No connection options were found in any orm configuration files" after deployed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, typeorm

Env:nodejs12

Folder structure:

```
#root
/functions
  /src
    ...
    /models
    /resolvers
    index.ts
  ormconfig.json
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  ...
.firebaserc
firebase.json
```

Everything worked when developing in local environment. After deployed to firebase functions, `No connection options were found in any orm configuration files` shows up.

What might be the cause?

I'll update with more information if needed.

=========================================

**update**

Below is the folder structure of deployed codes. (Cloud functions can't show more than 50 files so I downloaded the source code from GCP)

[image: folder structure]

[image: cloud functions SOURCE tab]

As you can see the `ormconfig.json` does exist in the root, but somehow it cannot be located. I have to create connection manually with `typeorm.createConnection({type: "postgres",...})` to make the code work.

Comment: I think deployment is not able to find ormconfig. There might be many reasons. I wonder how do you test it locally?

Comment: @vitooh with [Firebase Local Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite). when deploy, firebase build source code to `dist/` and uploaded the root folder to cloud functions, so local code should be same with deployed code.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely being caused by a [known bug](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path/issues/49) with app-root-path (which TypeORM [uses for config file resolution](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/3d876c61fafc815e429c68f4f4e1ab79e47c7b9c/src/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.ts#L205)) when used in conjunction with Google Cloud Functions.

The workaround / fix that worked for me was to set the environment variable `APP_ROOT_PATH` to `/workspace` when I deployed my Google Cloud Function (app-root-path will [short-circuit](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path/blob/54d06fef2340a36070fbfc24973bb676079aa7a1/lib/resolve.js#L52-L55) when it sees that variable).

Comment: I had to add that under environmental variables in the cloud console. I was trying to set variable on my local system and then deploy which didn't work which actually makes sense.

Comment: Thanks man, i had the same problem in Google app engine and adding APP_ROOT_PATH solved it :)